# Is there a way to speed up this MySQL delete query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, sql-delete

I’m using MySql 5.5.37.  I’m trying to figure out a faster way to write the below query.  I have two tables, access_code and classroom.  The “classroom” table has a foreign key constraint (access_code_id) to the primary key of the access_code table.  I’m trying to delete records in the access_code table that have no link to the classroom table and have a particular type id.  So I’m running …

```
delete from access_code where id in (select q.* from (select a.id FROM access_code a left join lyc_classroom c on a.id = c.access_code_id where a.access_code_type = 2 and c.access_code_id is null) q);
```

which is taking a very long time.  Is there a faster way to execute the above query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need subqueries. Use the `delete ... join` syntax

```
delete a 
from access_code a
left join lyc_classroom c on a.id = c.access_code_id
where a.access_code_type = 2 and c.access_code_id is null
```